# Dozens of forms handling

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am working on a project which has dozens of forms. Like :

`Laptops_form` | `Mobile_form` | `vehicles_form` | `Form_45`.

For each form the data is stored in a different table in the database.

I have 45 forms. A vast e-commerce web application.

Each database table has a representational page in the application where visitors will see the posted ads.

I am an intermediate level programmer. In this scenario I feel that it's the only way to do it. Is it right or is there another good way to achieve such goal in minimized way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what type of data is stored in those tables, if, for example, the data fields are similar but you need to differentiate between the forms, then you can just create one table and add a flag to it called form_type, and that table will store the data for all the forms.

If the data fields are completely different, they you can have (like what you have right now) a table for each form, or you can have a few dynamic tables (like when you're building a custom form). Personally, I favor your approach because it's faster when it comes to performance. The second approach, however, is more flexible and you'll be able to add more forms if you want to without creating additional tables - additionally, the reporting is much easier using the second approach.

Comment: The forms fields are not same ....

Comment: Please see updated answer that includes your case (where the fields are different).

Comment: Thanks buddy. 
I have to take care of performance and reporting also ! That's why selected this way ! But i was little confused and now i am clear.

Answer (score 1):

Itoctopus' comment is right considering the extend and explanation of your question, but... having variable numbers of tables per form isn't really very nice, and some databases may not be well optimised for that, where as any DB should be optimised for horrendous amounts of data. Also it will make your reporting more difficult, and one day you'll end up creating a table with a column that contains DB table names and find you can't write SQL that will join it together without using code to pull it out in 2 stages... So you should aim for a fixed schema.

It doesn't matter that the forms and fields are not the same, with the correct database design. Create a forms table, and a fields table (which links to a unique ID in the forms table). It might even be appropriate to add a URI column to the forms table if your pages map to forms 1 to 1, then a page can find a form without extra application logic and magic linkage. Any data storage and reporting is now really easy as you can have a data table which links to the unique ID in the forms column, and the solution is appropriately normalised.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, my second suggestion is actually what you're saying, but the thing is I know, from experience, is that performance wise (even with indexing) the first option is better. Otherwise, the second option is for sure better but requires some huge optimization efforts to make it work on a large scale.

Comment: I'm afraid I feel quite strongly that dynamic tables is a bad idea. I won't rule out a use case where dynamic tables is the correct solution, but I can't think of such a case. I can't think why performance would be any different, even if there were 100,000 forms with 10,000 fields each... in fact I would expect the reverse, and the more data (especially the more forms) the more inappropriate I would consider dynamic tables. What sort of "huge optimization" are you thinking of?